# C inline function generates Undefined symbols error

Tags: c, static, extern, function-declaration

I have read multiple search results about this including this link, but I still don't get it:
https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/porting_to.html

Why does this simple code generate a linker error:

```
#include <stdio.h>

inline int add(int a , int b){
 return a+b;
}

int main(){
 printf("%d\n", add(1,2));
 return 0;
}
```

All I want for the compiler to inline `add`. There are no other translation units, this is the only one. Why does it give me a `Undefined symbol` linker error?

While we are at it, I keep reading there is a difference between `inline add()` and `extern inline add()`. I thought all functions in `C` are `extern` by default?

error messgae:

```
$clang 0.c
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_add", referenced from:
      _main in 0-1cc8ba.o
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/vu39U6). I suspect the problem has nothing to do with `inline`, just with a broken compiler or environment.

Comment: What is your platform, compiler, OS, IDE, versions etc.? How do you compile? Did you try without `inline` (shouldn't change anything though)?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Try to run the program at www.ideone.com and you will get the error.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow cannot reproduce on [ideone](https://ideone.com/G89mWW) either. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Select the C99.

Answer (score 1):

From the C Standard (6.7.4 Function specifiers)

> 7. ...If all of the file scope declarations for a function in a translation
>      unit include the inline function specifier without extern, then the
>      definition in that translation unit is an inline definition. **An
>      inline definition does not provide an external definition for the
>      function**, and does not forbid an external definition in another
>      translation unit. An inline definition provides an alternative to an 
>      external definition, which a translator may use to implement any
>      call to the function in the same translation unit. **It is unspecified
>      whether a call to the function uses the inline definition or the
>      external definition.**

So it seems that the linker does not see the external definition of the inline function in your program.

To avoid the error use the storage specifier either `static` or `extern`.

For example

```
extern inline int add(int a , int b){
 return a+b;
}
```

or

```
static inline int add(int a , int b){
 return a+b;
}
```

Comment: @dbush It doesn't answer the question (mostly because the question cannot be answered because it cannot be reproduced, but that inherently disqualifies *any* answer, including this one).

Comment: @EOF This answers the question. The behavior is unspecified. So it can depend on the linker options. To avoid this dependency you can use explicitly the storage specifier.

Comment: @dbush  I am more outraged that the question was down-voted.:)