# How to define functions inside headers in c?

Tags: c, linker, inline, header-files

From `c++` I know the `inline` keyword in function means `every call to that function uses just one implementation` (and therefor there are no link error, like mulitple definition). I know `inline` is not the same in `c`, but I do not know the precise difference. But if I use `inline` to defined functions in header, include that header to `.c` source and use the `inline`d function from that header, then the linker cannot see them (undefined reference):

*new.h*:

```
#ifndef _NEW_H
#define _NEW_H

#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    void *(*ctor)(void *self, va_list *args);
    void *(*dtor)(void *self);
    void *(*clone)(const void *self);
    int (*differ)(const void *self, const void *x);
} class_t;

inline void *new (const void *_class, ...)
{
    const class_t *class = _class;
    void *p = calloc(1, class->size);

    assert(p);
    *(const class_t **)p = class;

    if (class->ctor)
    {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, _class);
        p = class->ctor(p, &args);
        va_end(args);
    }
    return p;
}

inline void delete (void *self)
{
    const class_t **p = self;
    if (self && *p && (*p)->dtor)
    {
        self = (*p)->dtor(self);
    }
    free(self);
}

//selector function (polymorphic function)
inline int _differ(const void *self, const void *x)
{
    class_t const *const *p = self;
    assert(self && *p && (*p)->differ);
    return (*p)->differ(self, x);
}

//selector func
inline size_t _sizeof(const void *type)
{
    class_t const *const *p = type;
    assert(type && *p);
    return (*p)->size;
}

extern void *clone(const void *);

#endif //_NEW_H
```

*main.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "new.h"

struct foo
{
    const void * class;
    size_t size;
    int val;
};

int main()
{
    struct foo f = {.size=24};
    void * p = new(&f);
    printf("%p\n",p);
}
```

then the error is:

```
 undefined reference to `new'
```

but the `new` function *is* defined in that header included. But it is defined as `inline`, so is that problem for linker? Why?

EDIT: neither `extern inline` (or just simple `extern`) helps here, because then it will throw error of `multiple definition`, So eihter `inline` or `extern` causes link/runtime errors.

Comment: Use the storage specifier extern.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Why should it be `extern`?  FWIW it will fail the same way if everything is in single C file: https://ideone.com/B4VXxR

Comment: @EugeneSh. See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374711/c-inline-function-generates-undefined-symbols-error/62374843#62374843

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Interesting. This one works though https://ideone.com/oSJl4V

Comment: @VladfromMoscow this does not work, becuase If I make all the `inline` functions `extern`, there will be multiple definition of them. that is `inline void *new (const void *_class, ...)` -> `undefined reference to new'`, but if extern: `extern inline void *new (const void *_class, ...)` -> multiple definition of `new'; So either case results in error